# Parse string value from URL

Tags: java, android, regex, string, split

I have a string (which is an URL) in this pattern `https://xxx.kflslfsk.com/kjjfkskfjksf/v1/files/media/93939393hhs8.jpeg`
now I want to clip it to this

```
media/93939393hhs8.jpeg
```

I want to remove all the characters before the second last slash `/`.

i'm a newbie in java but in swift (iOS) this is how we do this:

```
if let url = NSURL(string:"https://xxx.kflslfsk.com/kjjfkskfjksf/v1/files/media/93939393hhs8.jpeg"), pathComponents = url.pathComponents {
    let trimmedString = pathComponents.suffix(2).joinWithSeparator("/")
    print(trimmedString) // "output =  media/93939393hhs8.jpeg"
}
```

Basically, I'm removing everything from this Url expect of last 2 item and then.

I'm joining those 2 items using `/`.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: get  `media/93939393hhs8.jpeg` from  `https://xxx.kflslfsk.com/kjjfkskfjksf/v1/files/media/93939393hhs8.jpeg` @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with Regex? Try to use this [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/kN9aG2/1) (explained in the link) that captures the last 2 items separated with `/`:

```
.*?\/([^\/]+?\/[^\/]+?$)
```

Here is the example in Java (don't forget the escaping with `\\`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*?\\/([^\\/]+?\\/[^\\/]+?$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(string);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

---

Alternatively there is the `split(..)` function, however I recommend you the way above. (Finally concatenate separated strings correctly with `StringBuilder`).

```
String part[] = string.split("/");
int l = part.length;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String result = sb.append(part[l-2]).append("/").append(part[l-1]).toString();
```

---

Both giving the same result: `media/93939393hhs8.jpeg`

Answer (score 2):

```
String ret = url.substring(url.indexof("media"),url.indexof("jpg"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 string result=url.substring(url.substring(0,url.lastIndexOf('/')).lastIndexOf('/'));
```

or

Use Split and add last 2 items

```
  string[] arr=url.split("/");
  string result= arr[arr.length-2]+"/"+arr[arr.length-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String parseUrl(String str) {
    return (str.lastIndexOf("/") > 0) ? str.substring(1+(str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf("/")).lastIndexOf("/"))) : str;
}
```